# How to get output result of neural network in R

Tags: r, neural-network

```
 x1 = c(55, 60, 75, 80)
 x2 = c(30, 20, 15, 23)
 x3 = c(4, 3, 2, 6)
 x = data.frame(x1, x2, x3)
```

I used `neuralnet package` in R for neural network as follows:

```
    library(neuralnet)
    NN = neuralnet(x1 ~ x2 + x3, data = x, hidden = 2, threshold = 0.01)
    plot(NN)
```

In this plot the output is `x1` my question is that how to get the prediction values of output (I mean `x1`) however I used `prediction(NN)` but is give me all values of output and input . I want to give me just result of `output(x1)`.

[image: diagram of network]

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the `compute` function.

`?compute`

> compute, a method for objects of class nn, typically produced by neuralnet. Computes the outputs of all neurons for specific arbitrary covariate vectors given a trained neural network. Please make sure that the order of the covariates is the same in the new matrix or dataframe as in the original neural network.